# How to add Intellisense Tooltip Support for Library (dll)

Tags: c#, intellisense

How it is possible to provide the XML comments I've created in my Classes (in Library) for intellisense?

I've added to each method XML Comments like:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Do some connection request...
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="val">Required for xyz...</param>
    public void Connect(int val)
    {
        // Some code...
    }
```

Then I have marked the checkbox for create "XML documentation file" and give it a name "MyAssembly.xml". Rebuild my solution (one dll and one XML file are created).
Added the dll to another c# project, but the intellisense there doesn't show my XML comments...
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I've already read other threads about it on stackoverflow. Everywhere it says "Just mark the checkbox 'XML Documentation File' in the build section (output) and rebuild your solution"... I've rebuild it 1000 times...

Comment: Just for reference is this VS2005, VS2008 or VS2010?

Comment: Maybe you have intellisense turned off. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecfczya1(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Jason Hermann answer has solved my problem. Anyway, thanks ja72 and Alex Mendez for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way I was able to replicate your error was by giving the XML file a different name than the actual generated assembly.

Can you verify that the only difference between your assembly name and the XML name is the file extension?  The easiest way to do this is in the output folder where the EXE or DLL is created.

This was tested with C# and VS2010.  I hope it helps.

Comment: You're totally right. The given XML name was different to the DLL name. I've changed the name, rebuild my solution and now it works. Thanks alot. But why it must have extactly the same name (except the extension)?

Comment: I have no idea!  I just kept changing stuff until I could replicate your issue.  I'm guessing the assembly does not contain any information about the fact that it is documented in an external file, so visual studio can't do any better than just look for an XML file with the same name as the assembly.